# Clearing up a property of orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning the concept of principal component analysis and in one explanation I found the following statement:

Let's take an arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector $\textbf{v} = (v_1, ..., v_n)$ and orthonormal basis $\textbf{e}_1, \textbf{e}_2, ..., \textbf{e}_n$. We can write vector $\textbf{v}$ as:

$\textbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \textbf{e}_i * \langle\textbf{e}_i, \textbf{v}\rangle $

and

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle\textbf{e}_i, \textbf{v}\rangle^2 = 1 $ .

Why is the latter part true? Could someone maybe prove this? :) The $*$-sign denotes ordinary multiplication and $\langle \rangle$ denotes dot product :)

Here is the post i'm using as reference

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues/33654#33654

Thank your for any help!

Comment: The second equation is equivalent to state that $\|v\|^2=1$. Consider the vector $v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2$ in $\mathbb R^2$, with $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. Then $v_1=\langle v,e_1 \rangle$ and similarly for $v_2$ as $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation is equivalent to state that $\|v\|^2=1$. As easy example, consider the vector $v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2$  in $\mathbb R^2$, with $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. Then $v_1=\langle v,e_1 \rangle$ and similarly for $v_2$ as $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$. So you can write $v=\langle v,e_1 \rangle e_1+\langle v,e_2 \rangle e_2$. In the end
$$\|v\|^2=\langle v,e_1 \rangle^2+\langle v,e_2 \rangle^2 $$

Answer (score 3):

As fretty said, your right hand side of the second equation should be $\lvert v\rvert^2$.  To see this: use the first.  We know
$$
\lvert v\rvert^2=\langle v,v\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle e_i,v\rangle e_i,\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle e_j,v\rangle e_j\right\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\langle e_i,v\rangle\langle e_j,v\rangle\langle e_i,e_j\rangle.
$$
But, since $(e_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ is an orthonormal basis, we know that 
$$
\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if $i=j$}\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases},
$$
and so this simplifies as
$$
\lvert v\rvert^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle e_i,v\rangle^2,
$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

The second one isn't true, the RHS should be $||v||^2$. This is the analogue of Pythagoras' theorem in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think you were all right :-) I forgot to mention that v was unit vector :-)

Comment: So the real point is that in an arbitrary vector space it is a hassle to express something in terms of a basis...however when you have an inner product to play with and your basis is orthonormal with respect to that basis then this is actually simple (that is what the first result is telling you, the coeffs in the basis are the inner products with the basis elements). The second statement is telling you how easy it is to work out the length when you have an orthonormal basis.

Comment: This explains why finding longest side of a right angled triangle is easy but for non-right angled triangles it is not as easy...